# How does this functions work?

Tags: c

could someone explain me how this function works? I can'n understande the passage where it says k--, what does it means?
and when do i have to consider the last line? when the two " if " clauses are false?

```
int h(int n, int k)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if (g(i) && n%i==0) k--;
        if (k==0) return i;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not a question that can be answered. Ask a precise question, please.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate to ask someone that knows C in person. It is not a a good fit for SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

k--; it`s the same that k= k-1

When g(i) and n%i==0 are true,the function subtract 1 to k,

if k==0 then the function returns i; but if i>= n, then h returns 0.

The two " if " clauses are independent.

Without the function g we can`t say anything more.

Comment: `k--` is not the same as `k = k - 1`! There are semantical differences, e.g. the lvalue is not coerced for the side-effect (but the result is).

Comment: g gives 1 if " i " in g(i) is a prime number, otherwise it gives 0